# Regarding ifstream: error ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private

Tags: c++, fstream, c++98

I am getting the error in the title, when I try to do the following.

```
class Test
{
private:
    std::ifstream File;


public:
    Test();
```

};

Test::Test() {}

I know there are many threads on stack about this issue. I know that I can resolve my issue by something as simple as

```
std::ifstream *File;
```

The reason I have posted this question is because my instructor has told me that I should be able to do this without modifying the first code block I posted. I've researched this, and I haven't found anything that suggests I can. Any ideas?

As requested.

```
class Test
{
private:
    std::ifstream File;


public:
    Test();
};

Test::Test() {}

int main()
{
Test test = Test();
return 0;
}
```

That is an example of something I can't compile.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Sahu,  does the code I give not satisfy that? It demonstrates the exact issue I am having.

Comment: No,  it does not. I can't use just the posted code to reproduce the error you are seeing.

Comment: I'm sorry Sahu, I just noticed that I forgot to include the constructor which was giving me poblems. I just fixed that.

Comment: @JohnKraz what part of the code you are allowed to modify..
I meant you can do `Test test();` instead of `Test test = Test();`

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mubashir. I can't modify anything in the main. I can only make modifications in the public portion of the class.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Test test = Test();
```

is a problem since `std::ifstream` does not have a copy constructor or copy assignment operator. Use:

```
Test test;
```

If you have a C++11 compiler, you can also use:

```
Test test{};
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Sahu. Unfortunately I have to use that format 
" Test test = Test()" because my instructor requires it. We are only allowed to use C++98 compiler.

Comment: @JohnKraz, I hope you meant `Test test;` and not `Test test = Test();` since the second one will be a problem.

Comment: In the required driver we are given (which we can not modify), the object is created using the format "Test test = Test();". Will this still be a problem if I use "std::ifstream * File;"? My code compiles fine if I write it like that, but I would like your opinion on whether or not it will cause problems in the long run.

Comment: @JohnKraz, Using pointers is always more troublesome than using objects. Since you appear to be new to the language, I would advise using `std::ifstream File;`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will keep that into consideration, and see whether or not the instructor will allow me to use "Test test;"  so I can avoid    using the pointer.